# I need some clue to make a keystream based from an input

Tags: security, encryption, cryptography

well i have a project, but i didn't dive so deep into cryptography, here is my problem:

i want to generate a keystream based on a two input: a string and a 'file-size'
it's like if i have an input with a string = 'abcd' and a file with size of '10kbytes', the generated keystream will have a size of 80 kbytes, but if the file is '5kbytes' then the keystream size is 40kbytes

anyone know if there is some algorithm like this so i can learn more about this, or this is imposible / not exist?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is very basic cryptography, and may not be secure.  I assume this is a learning exercise, not for real use.  To learn more, read about stream ciphers, which generate a keystream.

First you need a key.  Since the key must be unique for each file, you will need to use a counter.  Concatenate your filename, file size and counter into a single string: "abcd-10kbytes-count0000001".  Keep track of your counter value and increment it each time you encrypt a file.

You now need to hash your concatenated string.  Your system may provide a secure hash like SHA256 or SHA3.  If it does then use one of them to produce a 256 bit key.  If you have to code the hash yourself, then try something much simpler to code, though insecure, such as [FNV hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fowler%E2%80%93Noll%E2%80%93Vo_hash_function) with 256 bit output.  The hash output is your encryption key.  Save it in a secure place, you will need it later for encrypting and decrypting the file.  Each file will have a different key.

For the stream cipher itself you can use AES-CTR (AES in counter mode) if it is available on your system.  If not, then code a much simpler stream cipher, like [RC4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC4).  This is obsolete and insecure but very easy to code.

AES-CTR and RC4 both produce a stream of bytes.  To encrypt the file, XOR the file with the keystream, byte by byte.  To decrypt the file, use the same key and again XOR the encrypted file with the keystream byte by byte.

If you find problems then ask again, showing your code with the problem.